Maximize database pooler TPS
I'm trying to maximize pooler and DB resources to ensure highest throughput.
Specs:
Postgres DB: 8CPUs 64GB Memory

VM for PGbouncer: 16CPU 64GB Memory

Both servers are on the same location.

As I'm using GCP SQL, max_connections and shared_buffers is already set to optimal value 800 and 22GB
PG bouncer config:

[databases]
reader = host=ip dbname=noname password=nopassword

[pgbouncer]

max_client_conn = 100000
default_pool_size = 40
max_db_connections = 43
pool_mode = "transaction"


Each PGbouncer can have max of 43 connections with DB and all 16instances will max out at 688connections which is well under max db connections.
My PGbouncer VM runs 16 pgbouncer isntances on 1001-1016 ports and I've haproxy which distributes load to all pgbouncer instances.

PG bench input file select.sql
SELECT 1;

When I run pgbench I get the following results:
max_client_conn=10000
  -c  |  -T    | TPS
---------------+-------
 500  |   120  | 60k
 1000 |   120  | 56k
 1500 |   120  | 55k

max_client_conn=100000(increased from 10,000 to 100,000)
  -c  |  -T    | TPS
---------------+-------
 500  |   120  | 47k
 1000 |   120  | 62k
 1500 |   120  | 63k
 2000 |   120  | 44k
 2500 |   120  | 38k
 3000 |   120  | 46k
 4000 |   120  | 46k
 5000 |   120  | 44k


increased DB max_buffer size from 21GB to 40GB

   -c  |  -T    | TPS
---------------+-------
 2000 |   120  | 69k
 5000 |   120  | 62k
 7000 |   120  | 60k
 10000|   120  | 64k


Note: There were no failures
My TPS is saturated at around 40-60k. Is there anything else that can be done to improve TPS?
Horizontally scaling pgbouncer instance is an option but you'll soon run into max_connections limit which is 800.

Pg bouncer held all db-connections and that explains the constant memory. CPU only spikes when I run a stress test.
When running stress test my PG bouncer vm had atmost of 50% CPU used but not much in memory.
Because this is just a SELECT 1 changing pool_mode from transaction to statement wont matter much.
Questions:

Is there anything I can do to improve TPS further? I know I can add read replicas and more pgbouncer instances. But is there anything I can do before I scale up?
Why did RPS improve when I increased max_buffer size?
I've 16pgbouncer instances and each instance has 43 backend connections(16 * 43 = 688). I can add 2 more pgbouncer instances or maybe increase backend connections to 49. Is this my only option?


Off-topic: you are aware that optimization for pgbench is different than optimization for your actual work load? And what changes did you make to PostgreSQL.conf?

What TPS do you get if you connect directly to the database (using a smaller number of connections of course)? You surely can't expect pgbouncer to scale beyond what the database itself can do.

@FrankHeikens PostgreSQL.conf the only change to max_buffer size from 21GB to 40GB.

@jjanes When I run pgbench -C 780(db max connections: 800) TPS is 35k which is much lower than what pgbouncer can acheive. This is because pgbouncer can run multiple transactions in a single connections.

-C is a switch, it does not take an argument.  Do you mean -c 780?  Did you also use -C as well as -c?  pgbench can't run multiple transactions over the same connection at the same time.

@jjanes Thanks for pointing out, its -c. I've updated question as well

You did not mention where you running pg_bench, did you check whether pg_bench itself having a bottleneck?

@goodfella I'm running pg_bench from another VM, what kind of bottlenecks can I expect? What should be doing in order to diagnose pg_bench?

@UdayReddy When we benchmarked using pg_bench we got CPU bottleneck in the machine where pg_bench were running. Were you able to check this VM?
